# Scroll to top button with jQuery not working in Safari v. 7.0.5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a Tumblr theme and I'm having some trouble with my back to top button. It seems to be working on Chrome and Firefox and newer versions of Safari but on my version of Safari (7.0.5) the  link works to direct the link back to the top but the animated scroll isn't working. Incase it helps I'm also using jquery version 1.10.1.

I've tried all sorts but can't see where I'm going wrong. I think there might be something thats conflicting with it but I'm not 100% sure.

Below is the code I'm using and here is a link to theme if inspecting would help.

http://minori-theme.tumblr.com

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<body>
    <a name="top">&nbsp;</a>

        <div class="wrapper">
            Main Content here
        </div>

     <a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
</body>
```

JS

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
            function scrollToAnchor(aid){
                var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
            }
            $("a").click(function() {
                var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
                scrollToAnchor(href);
            });         
        });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')`... you don't _have_ to use jQuery everywhere: `this.href.substring(1)`

Comment: Sorry could you explain I'm a bit confused?

Comment: `this.href.substring(1)` does the same thing, but does not require complex jQuery object modifications and access.

Comment: I see so you suggest I change var href= $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '') with this.href.substring(1) ?? If so I tried this and it doesn't seem to solve the issue. And it breaks the other two browsers also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to prevent the default behaviour of the anchor tag:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function scrollToAnchor(aid){
            var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
        }
        $("a").click(function(e) {
            //Add the e parameter to get the event object and call preventDefault.
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
            scrollToAnchor(href);
        });         
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the prevent default suggested broke all a links on the page and what i didn't realise was I had a height:100% on the body and html which was preventing the back to top button from working. After removing that the back to top works.